# Formatting the output using select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two select statements which are as mentioned below

```
SELECT 'MY OUTPUT'
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE
```

On execution **MY OUTPUT** is printed first and then there is a gap for next select.

I want to use something like `UNION` to combine two statements.

I'm using:

```
SELECT 'MY OUTPUT' UNION
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE
```

But, I am getting error:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: SQL stands for "Structurized Query Language" and is designed to make queries to a database and output a machine-understandable output. It is NOT designed for nice formatting.

Comment: How many columns does your table have, and can you list them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what's happening:

The error you're getting (All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.) is because there are more columns in one `select` than the other.

You could use the same blank columns in your first query as there are in `[My Table]` which would make your query look like:

```
SELECT 'MY OUTPUT' , '', '' ,'', '' --(no. of columns should match those in MY TABLE)
UNION
SELECT * FROM [MY TABLE]
```

I'm guessing you want an excel style cell merge which is not possible as the output of a `select` query unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'MY OUTPUT' # this query return one column
UNION 
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE # this query return more than one column
```

number of columns must be the same

```
SELECT 'MY OUTPUT' UNION # return one column
SELECT column1 FROM MY TABLE # return one column now it will work
```

but i think you want to do this no?

```
SELECT 'MY OUTPUT',column1,Column2,column3 FROM MY TABLE
```